# Connecting Raspberry Pis With I2C

Tags: i2c, connection

I would like to connect 6 slave RPis to 1 master RPi via I2C.  Has this been done before and is it even possible.  I know the I2C interface on the RPi has 1.8K pullup resistors so having all of those resistors in parallel might be an issue.

If someone has seen this done before a pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you will need to sort out is the client side i2c. You can not use either i2c bus you have access to on the broadcom as a client, (and if you could the kernel would still not support it.)

See here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8058/10699

You could bitbang an i2c client, (even using the same "i2c" pins but in GPIO mode.) But then you are adding performance issues to meet the timing requirements, and the RPi i2c host doesn't support clock stretching so you can't relax the timing.